# Paypal - Split payment and send it to different PayPal account

Tags: javascript, paypal

My goal is to get 5% of the amount and send it to Company PayPal account, and the other 95% will send directly to the Paypal of the other user. How can I do it in PayPal Code?

Here is my PayPal code.

```js
paypal.Button.render({
    style: {
        size: 'responsive',
        color: 'black'
    },
    env: 'sandbox', // 'sandbox' Or 'production',
    client: {
        sandbox: 'MyClientID',
        production: ''
    },
    locale: 'en_US',
    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
    payment: function(data, actions) {
    // Set up the payment here
    return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
            transactions: [{
                amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
            }]
        }
    });
},
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    // Execute the payment here
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
        console.log(payment);
    });
}
}, '#paypal-button');
```

Please help me.. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not possible with just a Paypal button. Paypal has its own way to split the money to whichever account you want to set it to and you'll need to use the Payouts API.

Note: It used to be "Adaptive Payments" but they (Paypal) stopped allowing new integrations.

According to the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/

> Use the Payouts API to make PayPal payments to multiple PayPal
>   accounts in a single API call. The Payouts API is a fast, convenient
>   way to send commissions, rebates, rewards, and general disbursements.

Please note that you'll need a paypal business account to be elligible for this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#

Comment: Ohh ok got it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: With the Payout API, does paypal put all the responsability of refunds on the marketplace side?

Comment: I have exactly the same use case. Did you get it work? Do I have to keep enough funds in my account in order to make payout (the 95% part)? How long is the delay?